# Wordpress how to update ACF field in a custom post type after the post has been saved

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to set the value of a field in a `custom post type` right after that post has been created. Here is my code:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'set_coach_email');
function set_coach_email( $post_id ){
    $posttype = get_post_type($post_id);
    if ('team' !== $posttype){
        return;
    }
    $email = 'test@test.com';
    update_field('coach_email', $email, $post_id);
}
```

I used `ACF fields` to create this custom post type, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Try to check if your if statement is correct. I would suggest using != btw. Other option is to insert a different email adress by the if statement and update field with this email adres. This way you can see if the problem is not with the if statement,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd check the opposite conditional check. Also i'd first check if the field is empty or not, then i'd only run the update if the field is empty.

```php
add_action('acf/save_post', 'set_coach_email');

function set_coach_email($post_id)
{
  $posttype = get_post_type($post_id);

  $email_field = get_field('coach_email', $post_id);

  if ('team' == $posttype && empty($email_field)) {

    $email = 'coachtest@test.com';

    update_field('coach_email', $email, $post_id);

  }
}
```

Just tested on my own custom post type and it worked fine. Let me know if you could get it to work too!

Comment: This worked for me. quick and effective with no extra fluff. Thank you very much @Ruvee.

Answer (score 1):

I find sometimes using `acf/save_post`, upping the priority makes sure everything else has run before running the action function.

This might come into play when passing an `$post_id` in the `get_field()` function, I tend not to pass the `$post_id` when using `acf/save_post` to make sure the current latest field data is used. But this theory might not be the case. See comments in code below...

```php
<?php

// save post action with priority 20 (default 10)
add_action('acf/save_post', 'set_coach_email', 20);

/**
 * @param $post_id int|string
 */
function set_coach_email($post_id) {

    // get our current post object
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // if post is object
    if(is_object($post)) {

        // check we are on the team custom type and post status is either publish or draft
        if($post->post_type === 'team' && ($post->post_status === 'publish' || $post->post_status === 'draft')) {

            // get coach email field
            $coach_email = get_field('coach_email');
            
            // if coach email field returns false
            if(!$coach_email) {

                // coach email default
                $email = 'coachtest@test.com';

                // update coach email field
                update_field('coach_email', $email, $post->ID);

            }

        }

    }

    // finally return
    return;

}
```